# Windows 10 speaker sound (voice) to text?

Tags: windows-10, text-to-speech, voice-command

I understand that I can voice control Windows 10, as well as I can create "voice to text" (dictate). Is there a way to simply display the speaker sound (in this very case my Spanish teacher speaking) as text?

It shall work a bit like YouTube "auto captions", simply displaying everything said as (Spanish) text.

1. Dictate works based on the MIC input, I would rather need to use the speaker output as source.
2. Dictate stops, I would need a permanent voice to text translation

Any way to configure Windows to do that? Or other solutions?

Comment: Had the same issue some days ago. The Speech-To-Text app of the Microsoft Store could not understand anything of a voice that came from the speakers. I had to speak in the micro, and even then, Speech-to-Text stops after a short while. Seems as if this app cannot fulfill the usual needs you would see for a Text-to-Speech app. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1):

Seems as if there is no Windows built-in program that can do that for now, although one can expect this in future, especially if the Windows assistant Cortana is already there, and with the Speech-To-Text app already available on a smaller scale.

Yet, for now, the "other solutions" are needed:

You need to search for an ASR (=STT) model, meaning "Automatic Speech Recognition" (=Speech-To-Text) model

A nice theoretical overview of ASR is at https://maelfabien.github.io/machinelearning/speech_reco/#.

As this question is about the practical side of it:

- You will either need to buy a Speech-To-Text program - I have once bought [Dragon NaturallySpeaking](https://www.nuance.com/dragon/transcription-solutions.html) of the market leader "Nuance" that was sold in combination with a [Philips VoiceTracer](https://www.dictation.philips.com/us/products/audio-video-recorders/voicetracer-audio-recorder-dvt2710/). This shall not advertise anything, it is just the way how I got my first Speech-To-Text program. I have never tested it, although doing that is still on my list :).
- Or you need to search for a pretrained model / train a model yourself.

I will just tell *how* I searched for it, which is the main answer, not the exact links. StackExchange is rather not about dropping some products or links, which is deemed rather off-topic. I have not tested anything and I am not a professional user.

Searching for ASR models, I found three pretrained models at "Hugging Face", which is an AI community that offers the seemingly most relevant choice of models, good if I only want to find few but relevant results at first: https://huggingface.co/models?pipeline_tag=automatic-speech-recognition.
Then I had a look at them in detail and found them to be trained on models which are publicly available on GitHub:

- Two are based on ESPnet. Mind that ESPnet2 is going to come soon. A demo is available at https://github.com/espnet/espnet#asr-demo.
- The Facebook model is based on wav2vec model at https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/tree/master/examples/wav2vec#wav2vec-20.

Then we see here that everything starts and ends on GitHub, which should not surprise. On GitHub, you would want to search for ASR, STT, Automatic Speech Recognition, Speech-To-Text, and perhaps just "speech", as I did, sorting the results by stars, to find "Mozilla DeepSpeech" to be the most promising project: https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech#project-deepspeech.

For Chrome, there is [SpeechTexter](https://www.speechtexter.com/) which supports all of the various dialects of Spanish.

You should try the free version of [Google Speech-to-Text](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/).

Also, if you search with the right keywords and add your language, you will find models that are pretrained in your needed language, for example

- "speech spanish" leads to https://github.com/luchovelez/SpeechRecognition
- "deepspeech spanish" shows six results with few to no stars (which shall not say that they will not work): https://github.com/search?q=deepspeech+spanish&type=Repositories

If you go on searching like this, you will find more projects. You will usually not need any programming skills, the demos are more a copy and paste job. The only thing needed is to have the right programming framework at hand.

Mind that some models or programs need a chosen sample rate as input, for example 16 KHz. You will sometimes need to reformat your audio files or your audio input.

Comment: Thanks for that excellent summary/overview!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am currently using:

1. I have used a software (in my case VOICEMEETER) which allows me to redirect my sound output to 2 devices. An extern software is used because Windows Mixer in my case is no option ([Windows mixer "not mixing" with headset, but with another output device. Why?](https://superuser.com/q/1620986/72397)).
2. VOICEMEETER allows me to route back the output sound to a (virtual) input device. So I have now a VIRTUAL input device which reads back the output sound.
3. Next I set the Microphone in Google Chrome to that VIRTUAL input device [image: Chrome Mic]
4. Hence I can use Google translate to create a transcript. This works with any sound, so I could also playback music or video. [image: Google translate showing the transcript].

A litte summary:

- My use case is that I want so see the transcript of my Spanish teacher speaking
- I now can simply achieve that my going to "Google Translate" and press the MIC button
- It is even possible for me to see the Spanish AND English text at the same time
- I need VOICEMEETER because I still need to hear my teacher (Zoom conference) and redirecting the output at the same time
- Windows mixer did not work for me, see the linked post
- I have tried other apps like Firefox or Word dictate. The problem here is that I cannot change the MIC (it uses the DEFAULT input device), and I need the MIC itself for talking to my teacher. See [Change microphone for Word/Outlook Dictate only (Win10)?](https://superuser.com/q/1620561/72397)
- I am not affiliated in any way with VOICEMEETER, anyway kudos to those guys - nice UI and tool.

Shortcomings:

- Google Translate has a word/duration limit - in my case it is irrelevant, but it might matter for other use cases
- The solution is browser based so far

Legal FOO:

- make sure you meet the legal requirements in your country, check if it is legal to create a transcript of a conference/audio/video call
- Also check the Google etc.Terms/Conditions to verify if this approach is covered