# Change microphone for Word/Outlook Dictate only (Win10)?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, audio, microsoft-outlook

I can setup my recording device in Windows 10 under Sounds. This is the microphone taken for Dictate in Word and Outlook.

However, I want to use **2 microphones** (e.g. one for Zoom, and a **2nd one for Dictate**). I have found that there should be an option to individually select those per application, but neither Word nor Outlook is visible there for me.

Any alternative I can use?

[image: Advanced sound options]

Using advanced sound options from Sound Settings, then:

[image]

Some programs show here, but unfortunately NEITHER word NOR Outlook 365

[image: Settings with Gawin]

No idea why GADWIN shows here, but not Word 365.....

---

Slightly related to my question here: [Windows 10 speaker sound (voice) to text?](https://superuser.com/q/1620408/72397)

Comment: You mention that you "found that there should be an option to individually select those per application” ... where did you find that? My experience is to the contrary. Speakers and Microphones are hardware devices controlled by the OS, not individual applications. Maybe if you gave each device an application specific name that would help you choose your Outlook device versus your Zoom device ... but that is just a label that has nothing to do technically with the running application.

Comment: Have updated the topic to make clear how to open and how it looks with an application. Outlook and Word were open at the time of the screenshots BUT DO NOT show in that options.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, this is impossible, we could not change the sound input and output devices separately for the Outlook program. I did wanted to change Outlook reminders sound to a specific audio device before, but could not make it. Sounds like what you want is similar as what I tried before.

Comment: I see, only strange that some of MS' major programs as Word or Outlook do not appear in the `App volume and device preferences`.

Comment: Yes, exactly, it indeed could not be found there.